# How to transfer a excel into a sql database in python

Tags: sql, excel, database

I just started studying data science and I'm trying to figure out how to turn excel into a SQL database.

Comment: Using an external table may be a better option.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to make a script to populate it like this.`import cs50

```
import csv
import re

def main():
    # Open SQL database
    creatives_data = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///# the sql file path here")

    # Open csv file
    with open("#the excel file path here", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        source_reader = []
        temp = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        i = 0
        for row in temp:
            source_reader.insert(i, row)
            i = i + 1

    for row in source_reader:

        creatives_data.execute(
            f"INSERT INTO #the sql table name (#the row name in excel) values (?)", row["OXY"])
main()
```

Comment: FYI the OP hasn't shown any work or any details. What you wrote... isn't related to any code the OP has written.

Comment: i mean yea but its a general answer

Comment: Sure, but... Stack Overflow isn't a place to post general requirements and have others write code to implement those requirements. The OP either needs to ask a specific question, along with showing work, or the question should be closed. No answer should be posted.